# Flutter - VS Code Flutter Emulator is broken

Tags: java, android, flutter

I want to run Android Emulator for the Flutter project, from VS Code.
But, as a result, I got this:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Kotlin could not find the required JDK tools in the Java installation '/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home' used by Gradle. Make sure Gradle is running on a JDK, not JRE.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Interesting is, I can run the app from Android Studio, but from VS Code I can't.
How and why is this possible? :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might have Java 16, Try install Java 11 or  Java 8
Google needs free itself from all that envolves the java. It's so boring setuping all.